# Can the norm of the sum of two vectors become negative?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra

Consider a vector $x=(x_1,...,x_N)$, then I define vectors $X,Y$ as

$X_i:=\frac{2}{N} x_i$ and $Y_i:=-\frac{2}{N^2} \sum_{j \neq i } \frac{x_i-x_j}{\vert x_i- x_j \vert^2}.$

It follows then that

$$ \vert X+Y \vert^2= \frac{4}{N^2} \vert x \vert^2 + \frac{4}{N^4} \sum_{i=1}^N \vert \sum_{j \neq i } \frac{x_i-x_j }{\vert x_i-x_j \vert^2} \vert^2+ -\frac{4}{N^3} \sum_{i \neq j } \left( x_i-x_j \right) \frac{\left(x_i-x_j\right)}{\vert x_i-x_j \vert^2}$$

Thus, $$ \vert X+Y \vert^2= \frac{4}{N^2} \vert x \vert^2 + \frac{4}{N^4}  \sum_{j \neq i } \frac{1}{\vert x_i-x_j \vert^2}  -\frac{4(N-1)}{N^2}.$$

However, now I noticed something super strange, if you take $x=(1,1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{3},..,1/\sqrt{N})$ then this expression $\vert X+Y \vert^2$ is negative.

More precisely, if $N=10$ then this expression is negative, I enclosed a Mathematica output as proof:

[image]

Mathematica then gives $-0.023689.$

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: What does $X_i=\frac 2 N x$ mean? How do you get $x_i-x_j$ from the components of $X$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sorry $X_i=2/N x_i$. $(x_i-x_j)$ comes from symmetry

Comment: @JohnHughes I think the minus should be there as $Y_i$ has a negative sign (thus so has the mixed there $2X_iY_i$ in the binomial formula)

Comment: That image only contains your input, not the output.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos it is -0.023689

Comment: It is obvious that $|X+Y|^2\ge0$. Your mistake is either in the expansion of the formula using summations, or in your Mathematica input.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, that is precisely the question

Comment: There's a typo in the factor multiplying the second term of the formula in the body of the question (but not in the Mathematica expression). It should be $\ \frac{4}{N^4}\ $, not $\ \frac{4}{N^2}\ $. The Mathematica expression has the correct $\ \frac{4}{K^4}\ $.  What does the operation N[.] do in Mathematica?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera thank you, corrected. N[] gives a numerical value, which is the $-0.023...$ .

Comment: Mh, I thought that it was "Can the norm of the sum of two vectors become negative?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have calculated $x_i-x_j$ wrongly. It is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}$, not $\sqrt{i}-\sqrt{j}$.

Answer (score 3):

You claim that if I take $x$ to be your specific sequence, then $|X+Y|^2$ is negative.

Picking $N = 1$, we get $X = [2]$ and $Y = [0]$. The left hand side is $|[2]|^2 = 4$. The right hand side is... uh ...
\begin{align}
\vert X+Y \vert^2 
&= 4/N^2 \vert x \vert^2 + 4/N^2 \sum_{i=1}^N \vert \sum_{j \neq i } \frac{x_i-x_j }{\vert x_i-x_j \vert^2} \vert^2+ -4/N^3 \sum_{i \neq j } \left( x_i-x_j \right) \frac{\left(x_i-x_j\right)}{\vert x_i-x_j \vert^2} \\
&= 4  + 4/N^2  \cdot 0 -4/N^3 \cdot 0 \\
&= 4.
\end{align}

This is conspicuously *not* negative.

One (serious) suggestion: replace $4/N^2$ with $\frac{4}{N^2}$ throughout, so that it's easier to read. Then, as soon as possible, multiply though by $N^2$ or even $N^3$ to get rid of most of the fractions, without changing the sign on anything.

Comment: The issue is for $N=10$ not for $N=1$, please look at the mathematica output.

Comment: (1) You wrote "However, now I noticed something super strange, if you take $=(1,1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{3}, ,\ldots, 1/\sqrt{N})$ then this expression $|+|^2$ is negative." I showed this was false for $N = 0$. When you say something false, and someone show's you've got it wrong, the right response is "thank you, I'll be able to find my error now,"  not "I didn't say that." (2) Your formula is wrong, as Jose already noted. (3) The Mathematica output shows that if you evaluate two different things, it's possible you'll get two different answers. I don't need to look at the output to know that.

Comment: it is just that I disagree with your answer and in my question I tried to make it clear that the issue is with $N=10$, not with $N=0$.